# How to distinguish python 3.9.1 and python 3.9.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my computer there are both python 3.9.1 which I downloaded myself and 3.9.7 which comes along with anaconda. And I faced problems when I wanted to install package into one of them. Currently I used `python3.9 -m pip install pack_name` to install the package. But it does not differentiate 1 or 7. It seems it will try to install for both. Also when I type `python3.9 -V` it shows 3.9.7 in computer's terminal but shows 3.9.1 in vscode's terminal... I tried to change version in `Python:select interpreter` of vscode but it made no difference. I tried `python3.9.1 ...` but that is not a command;(.

Is there any way to specifically use one of them?

Comment: i think you should check out [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). This tool lets you use multiple python versions easily

Comment: Use the full path to the Python interpreter you want to use, which you can get using `where`, or else set up a virtual environment.

Comment: you should be using virtual environments, in this case, probably just use `conda` for virtual environments